# Continuing seuda in new place

Tags: blessing, meal-seudah, intent-accident-purposely, hamotzi-beracha

Can i continue my hamotzi seuda in a place I didn't have in mind when I washed/started eating? If so, do I need to have a kzayis of bread in that place, or just a kzayis of anything in the meal?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [O.C. 178:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49624&st=&pgnum=158) and particular Mishnah Brurah #3. Even if you move to a different room in the same home, you need to say Birkat Hamazon retroactively on what you ate in the first location, wash, and say *hamotzi* to continue your seudah in the new location.

It is different if you are part of a group and you exit leaving your group there. In such a situation, you don't need to say a new bracha. See 178:2 for details.